# ¿Por qué se cierra mi app?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, activity

Genero dos números aleatorios: NumU y NumD, con un rango y el método aleatorio, todo bien y tal, pero al iniciar la activity, esta se cierra.
Viendo en el log cat, arroja esto:

> 2021-03-28 22:02:34.438 13208-13208/com.danysoftware.practmate
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.danysoftware.practmate, PID: 13208
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.danysoftware.practmate/com.danysoftware.practmate.MainActivity}:
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
> #0x5b
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5b
> at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:413)
> at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6427)
> at com.danysoftware.practmate.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:46)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8086)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8074)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1313)

me dice que en linea 46 de MainActivity (Que para ustedes seria la que esta comentada en mayusculas), veamos que hay en ella:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var operando:Char = 'a'
var txtOperando: TextView? = null
var txtNumUno: TextView? = null
var txtNumDos: TextView? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    /*
    var Puntuacion: Int = 300*/

    txtOperando = findViewById(R.id.txtOp)
    txtNumUno = findViewById(R.id.txtNumU)
    txtNumDos = findViewById(R.id.txtNumD)
    var NumU:Int = 0
    var NumD:Int = 0
    txtNumUno?.setText("")
    txtNumDos?.setText("")


    val operacion = intent.getStringExtra("operacion")
   /* Toast.makeText(this, operacion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()*/

    NumU = (1..100).random()
    NumD = (1..100).random()

    if(operacion.equals("suma")){
        operando = '+'
        txtOperando?.setText(operando.toString())
        txtNumUno?.setText(NumU)//ESTA ES LA LINEA 46
        txtNumDos?.setText(NumD)
    }else{
        if (operacion.equals("resta")){
            operando = '-'
            txtOperando?.setText(operando.toString())
            txtNumUno?.setText(NumU)
            txtNumDos?.setText(NumD)
        }else{
            if (operacion.equals("multiplicacion")){
                operando = '*'
                txtOperando?.setText(operando.toString())
                txtNumUno?.setText(NumU)
                txtNumDos?.setText(NumD)
            }else{
                if (operacion.equals("division")){
                    operando = '/'
                    txtOperando?.setText(operando.toString())
                    txtNumUno?.setText(NumU)
                    txtNumDos?.setText(NumD)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edtxtResp)
    var textoRec = editText.text

    var Primero:Boolean = true
    val btnComprobar = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnComprobar)
    btnComprobar.setText("Empezar!")
    btnComprobar.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        var resPar:Int = NumU + NumD

        if(resPar.toString().equals(textoRec)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Correcto +100",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Inorrecto -100",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }})}}
```

Porque se cierra la app y me da el error, si aparentemente todo esta bien?
Que solución le puedo dar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tus variables `NumU` y `NumD` son de tipo `Int`. El argumento que debes pasarle a `setText()` tiene que ser un `String` o un `Int` que sea el id de algún string resource.
Cuando haces esto `txtNumUno?.setText(NumU)` la aplicación busca en tu arhivo `res/values/strings.xml` un string que tenga ese id y como no lo encuentra se produce una `NotFoundException` que hace que tu app se cierre.

La solución es convertir el valor de las variables a String

```
txtNumUno?.setText(NumU.toString())
```

que también se puede escribir así

```
txtNumUno?.setText("$NumU")
```

Comment: Master, me haz ayudado dos veces en el dia; te agradezco demasiado bro. 
Eres todo un crack en eso